# How to prevent a process starting?

Tags: linux, process, gentoo

I have [synergyc](http://synergy-foss.org/) process that starts at boot. How do I prevent this process from starting? I've searched `/etc`, `/etc/init.d` for some configs or scripts but found nothing.

Comment: Are you sure it actually starts at boot, rather than at desktop login? My synergys (server rather than client) process is started by a .desktop file in $HOME/.config/autostart.

Comment: On my linux `synergyc` owner is `root` so i think is started at boot. I'm logged as another user and `~/.config/` have nothing related to this process :(

Answer (score 2):

Look in */etc/rc*.d/* for it..

Also check */etc/rc.local*

You could also just add a line to /etc/rc.local, like "*killall synergyc*" - though if that's called too soon, then it won't help - so you could write a cron script for that. Yeah, it's kinda messy.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but nothing like `/etc/rc.d/` or `/etc/rc.local` exists on Gentoo Linux. Gentoo Linux instead has `/etc/conf.d/local.start`, but is empty right now.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- Check if it has a parent PID that is still alive
- Temporarily replace synergyc by a shell script that prints information about the parent process to a file, to find the parent process.
- udev/hotplug scripts may start processes
- Maybe it added a line to `/etc/inittab`
- Do you use a display manager? It may be started from there.

Comment: parent PID is 1 - `init` process; `grep -R synergyc /etc/udev/` return nothing; nothing related to `synergyc` in `/etc/inittab`; I'm using `xdm` display manager, but `grep -R synergyc /etc/X11/` or `grep -R synergyc /etc/X11/xdm/` return nothing too.

Answer (score 1):

It's really strange that `synergyc` is owned by root, you'd better start it in your user session.

Check [this](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/autostart.html) guide about synergy autostart, there are examples of startup configurations for several desktop managers.